# Redux-persist dropping part of initial state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am adding [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to my React Native app, and after running `persistStore` it is not copying part of the state that holds scenes from my app. Why is `persistStore` dropping this part of my state?

Specifically, I am using [NavigationExperimental](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) and adding the different routes to the state. Within a given route, the key is present, but the component holding the scene is absent.

Here's the code where this is occurring:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import store from '../reducers/store.js';
import Container from './container.js';

//Import API keys
import firebaseConfig from '../../api_keys.js';

export default class Index extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { rehydrated: false };
 }

 componentWillMount() {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // store.getState() contains scenes
  persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, () => {
   // store.getState() does not contain scenes
   this.setState({ rehydrated: true });
  });
 }

 render() {
  console.log('rehydrated is: ', this.state.rehydrated);
  if (!this.state.rehydrated) {
   return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  return (
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Container />
   </Provider>
  );
 }
}
```

And here's the relevant code where I'm creating the store.

```js
const store = createStore(
 reducer,
 INITIAL_STATE,
 compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
  autoRehydrate()
 )
);

export default store;
```